# Failed to reach to yellow star icon

Tags: far-cry-4

There is a yellow star icon showing in the minimap of Far Cry4, but I cannot find it in the actual map.  I have tried to reach the point but I have failed

Comment: It's probably underground.

Comment: In some cases it could also be above you. Definitely look for a cave/cavern entrance first though as @Carcigenicate had mentioned - It could be below you.